# Compile error in extension NSLayoutAnchor

Tags: swift, uikit, nslayoutanchor

I am trying to create an extension method on NSLayoutAnchor to accept a multiplier.  I get a weird Swift compile error (Swift 3, XCode 8.2.1) not in the extension file but in the corresponding .h file (this file is automatically generated by the compiler) for the module:

```
@interface NSLayoutAnchor (SWIFT_EXTENSION(MYMODULENAME))
- (NSLayoutConstraint * _Nonnull)constraintTo:(NSLayoutAnchor</* AnchorType */> * _Nonnull)anchor multiplier:(CGFloat)m;
@end
```

The error points to `/* AnchorType */` and says: "Expected a type".  Well, that makes sense since `/* AnchorType */` is not a type but a comment.  However I am using the `AnchorType` type parameter in the method signature.

The extension source code is as follows:

```
extension NSLayoutAnchor {
  open func constraint(to anchor: NSLayoutAnchor<AnchorType>, multiplier m: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
  // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This extension is in a separate module from my main project.  When I move the extension code inside my main project everything works fine.  This must be some sort of mixup in building the module interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTE: Fixed as of Swift 4, see benrudhart's answer below.**

This is currently an issue with swift and objc. Extending objc generics in swift then bridging back into objc is not allowed. Even adding a `@nonobjc` doesn't fix the issue. Take a look at the bug filed here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2708 for more info.

A potential fix is to make an extension on each concrete type of `NSLayoutAnchor`. The concrete types are `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor`, `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor` and `NSLayoutDimension`.

```
extension NSLayoutDimension {
    open func constraint(to anchor: NSLayoutDimension, 
             multiplier m: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint
}

extension NSLayoutXAxisAnchor {
    open func constraint(to anchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor, 
             multiplier m: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint
}

extension NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    open func constraint(to anchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor, 
             multiplier m: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Swift 4 this is now possible by annotating the extension with `@objc`. The following code will compile:

```
@objc extension NSLayoutAnchor {
    func constraint(to anchor: NSLayoutAnchor<AnchorType>, multiplier: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
        // ...
    }
}
```